# RxJava Scan emits first item, other RX libraries do not. Why?

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-swift

The scan() operator that takes a seed in RxJava emits the seed upon every subscription. Other RX languages, like RxJS & RxSwift do not do this. Seed value is never emitted.

Why is this? Is it safe to assume RxJava has an added feature where other RX languages never expected a scan to act like that.

**RxJs & RxSwift**
[image: RxJS & RxSwift]

**RxJava**
[image: RxJava]

Comment: I can't remember why RxJava did this pretty much from the start. My guess is that by using `skip(1)`, you can always omit the first item from scan if you wanted. You can `startWith` the seed but that adds more overhead.